# Is there a way to identify manually logged activities in Google Health Connect?

Tags: healthconnect

I am looking to integrate Google Health connect in my Android fitness app. Is there a way to identify manually logged steps and sleep data by user in Health Connect app or companion wearable app (connected to health connect)?

I looked into Health connect documentation but couldn't figure out

Comment: As of now there is no way to do this in health connect...Hope they will add this as a feature request after some time

Answer (score 0):

You can, you can find it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/metadata/Metadata) and its one of the public constructors of the metadata, namely [recordingMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/metadata/Metadata#recordingMethod()).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm getting unknown method for all data coming from Google Fit currently.